# A problem regarding Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences, congruence-relations

Solve $371x\equiv 287\mod460$ using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

So far I've done
$$460=4\times5\times23$$

Then the given congruence is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
371x&\equiv287\mod4\\
371x&\equiv287\mod5\\
371x&\equiv287\mod23
\end{align*}

How to advance from here?

Comment: Reduce each of $371$ and $287$ modulo $4, 5, 23$ respectively.

Comment: After you perform the reduction, multiply by the appropriate modular inverses, then solve using CRT.

Comment: Do you have to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem? One application of the extended Euclidean algorithm suffices to find the inverse of $371 \bmod 460$.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg How to reduce the $3^{rd}$ one?

Comment: @BernhardListing Well, $3x\equiv 11\mod 23$ after you have reduced modulo $23$

Comment: @Peter How have you come here? Could you provide the steps? I'm finding it a bit problematic.

Comment: $371\mod 23=3$ and $287\mod 23=11$

Comment: And solving $3x\equiv 11\mod 23$ should be no problem. Just multiply with $8$ and consider $24\equiv 1\mod 23$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the *extended Euclidean algorithm* to obtain a *Bézout's relation* between $371$ and $460$:
\begin{array}{r|rr|l}
r_i&u_i&v_i&q_i\\
\hline
460&0&1\\
371&1&0&1\\
89&-1&1&4\\
15&5&-4&5\\14&-26&21&1\\1&31&-25
\end{array}
Thus a Bézout's  relation is
$$31\cdot 371-25\cdot460=1$$
so that the inverse of $371$ mod. $460$ is $31$, and the solutions are
$$31\cdot 371 x\equiv x\equiv 31\cdot 287\equiv 157\mod 460.$$